# Assembly division not working properly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I'm working on a program for my CS class that is supposed to ask the user for numbers until a number outside of the specified range is entered, at which point it will print the number of numbers entered, the sum, and the average. I have all of this written out, however the average is giving me really strange numbers and I'm really stumped with trying to find a solution. 
Here's my code:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

LOWERLIMIT = -100
UPPERLIMIT = -1

.data

TextOne BYTE "Welcome to the Integer Accumulator" ,0
PromptOne BYTE "What is your name? " ,0
TextTwo BYTE "Hello, " ,0
TextThree BYTE "Please enter numbers in [-100, -1]." ,0
TextFour BYTE "Enter a non-negative number when you are finished to see results." ,0
PromptTwo BYTE "Enter number: " ,0
TextFive BYTE "You entered " ,0
TextSix BYTE " valid numbers" ,0
TextSeven BYTE "The sum of your valid numbers is " ,0
TextEight BYTE "The rounded average is " ,0
TextNine BYTE "Thank you for playing Integer Accumulator! It's been a pleasure to meet you, " ,0
TextTen BYTE "." ,0
NoNums BYTE "Looks like you didn't enter any valid numbers..." ,0

Username BYTE 33 DUP(0)

CurNum DWORD ?
NumNumbers DWORD 0
Sum DWORD 0
Average DWORD 0

.code
main PROC

;--Introduction--
    mov edx, OFFSET TextOne
    call WriteString
    call CrLf

;Get user's name
    mov edx, OFFSET PromptOne
    call WriteString
    mov edx, OFFSET UserName
    mov ecx, 32
    call ReadString

;print user's name
    mov edx, OFFSET TextTwo
    call WriteString
    mov edx, OFFSET UserName
    call WriteString
    call CrLf
    call CrLf

;print instructions
    mov edx, OFFSET TextThree
    call WriteString
    call CrLf
    mov edx, OFFSET TextFour
    call WriteString
    call CrLf

;--Main Loop--

Mainloop:

;get user input
    mov edx, OFFSET PromptTwo
    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    mov CurNum, eax

;check upper bound
    mov eax, CurNum
    cmp eax, UPPERLIMIT
    jg Endloop

;check lower bound
    mov eax, CurNum
    cmp eax, LOWERLIMIT
    jl Endloop

;if number is valid, NumNumbers is incremented by 1 and CurNum is added to sum
    inc NumNumbers

    mov eax, CurNum
    add eax, Sum
    mov Sum, eax

;loops again
    jmp Mainloop





Endloop:

;checks if any valid numbers were entered, and if no valid numbers were entered, then prints message and skips to end
    mov eax, NumNumbers
    cmp eax, 0
    jg Valid
    mov edx, OFFSET NoNums
    call WriteString
    call CrLf
    jmp NoNumbers

Valid:





;--Results--

;Displays numbers of items
    mov edx, OFFSET TextFive
    call WriteString
    mov eax, NumNumbers
    call WriteDec
    mov edx, OFFSET TextSix
    call WriteString
    call CrLf

;Displays sum of numbers
    mov edx, OFFSET TextSeven
    call WriteString
    mov eax, Sum
    call WriteInt
    call CrLf

;--Compute average--
    mov edx, 0
    mov eax, Sum
    mov ebx, NumNumbers
    div ebx
    mov Average, eax

;Displays rounded average
    mov edx, OFFSET TextEight
    call WriteString
    mov eax, Average
    call WriteInt
    call CrLf

NoNumbers:

;Prints goodbye message
    mov edx, OFFSET TextNine
    call WriteString
    mov edx, OFFSET UserName
    call WriteString
    mov edx, OFFSET TextTen
    call WriteString
    call CrLf




    exit    ; exit to operating system
main ENDP

; (insert additional procedures here)

END main
```

This segment is giving me the issue:

```
    ;--Compute average--
    mov edx, 0
    mov eax, Sum
    mov ebx, NumNumbers
    div ebx
    mov Average, eax
```

As an example, I'll enter -1 three times, and then enter 1 and it will output 4294967295 instead of the expected average value of -1.

I then also used idiv and cdq, but I'm running into the same issue as above, with the same output

```
;--Compute average--
    mov edx, 0
    mov eax, Sum
    cdq
    mov ebx, numNumbers
    idiv ebx
    mov Average, eax
```

I'd really appreciate a hand, and thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: "strange numbers" is not a good error description. Provide exact inputs, actual and expected outputs. Also, learn to use a debugger.

Comment: `div` will certainly not support negative values, but `idiv` variant looks ok on first read, so you will have to use debugger to figure out which detail is ruining it. .. btw, you can `idiv` directly from memory, like `idiv dword ptr [numNumbers]`, if you already insist on storing that value into memory instead of keeping it around in register all the time. This won't fix your bug of course. And no need to `mov edx,0` when you do `cdq` any way.

Answer (score 1):

`4294967295` and `-1` have the same binary representation in [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), so your calculation is right but you're printing it as unsigned instead of signed.

Search the Irvine32 docs for a function that prints signed integers.